# Wix installer build failure : error CNDL0103: The system cannot find the file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, wix

I am trying to create a Wix CustomActions Assembly to set installer properties at msi installation time for my VS2012 c# solution. In the IDE when I right click and build the installer for the web service (OU.Curriculum.ProductService) I get the following error:

```
The system cannot find the file 'obj\Debug\VantageInstallerCustomActions_Generated.wxs' with type 'Source'. candle.exe OU.Curriculum.ProductService.Installer
```

The last few lines of the build output shows the following:

```
2>  C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\Heat.exe dir O:\TFS\Vantage\Curriculum\source\OU.Curriculum.Products-Release2.1-Dev-Violet\OU.Curriculum.ProductService\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\ -cg OU.Curriculum.ProductService_Generated -dr INSTALLFOLDER -scom -sreg -srd -var var.OU.Curriculum.ProductService_Generated.Target -gg -sfrag -t O:\TFS\Vantage\Curriculum\source\OU.Curriculum.Products-Release2.1-Dev-Violet\OU.Curriculum.ProductService.Installer\WsxExcludeWebConfig.xslt -out obj\Debug\OU.Curriculum.ProductService_Generated.wxs
2>  C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\Heat.exe project O:\TFS\Vantage\Curriculum\source\OU.Curriculum.Products-Release2.1-Dev-Violet\OU.Curriculum.ProductService\OU.Curriculum.ProductService.csproj -configuration Debug -directoryid INSTALLFOLDER -platform AnyCPU -pog Binaries -pog Symbols -pog Sources -pog Content -pog Satellites -pog Documents -projectname OU.Curriculum.ProductService -ag -sfrag -out obj\Debug\_OU.Curriculum.ProductService.wxs
2>  C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\candle.exe -dVantageInstallerCustomActions_Generated.Target=O:\TFS\Vantage\Curriculum\source\OU.Curriculum.Products-Release2.1-Dev-Violet\VantageInstallerCustomActions\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\ -d"DevEnvDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\\" -dSolutionDir=O:\TFS\Vantage\Curriculum\source\OU.Curriculum.Products-Release2.1-Dev-Violet\ -dSolutionExt=.sln -dSolutionFileName=OU.Curriculum.Products.sln -dSolutionName=OU.Curriculum.Products -dSolutionPath=O:\TFS\Vantage\Curriculum\source\OU.Curriculum.Products-Release2.1-Dev-Violet\OU.Curriculum.Products.sln -dConfiguration=Debug -dOutDir=bin\Debug\ -dPlatform=x86 -dProjectDir=O:\TFS\Vantage\Curriculum\source\OU.Curriculum.Products-Release2.1-Dev-Violet\OU.Curriculum.ProductService.Installer\ -dProjectExt=.wixproj -dProjectFileName=OU.Curriculum.ProductService.Installer.wixproj -dProjectName=OU.Curriculum.ProductService.Installer -dProjectPath=O:\TFS\Vantage\Curriculum\source\OU.Curriculum.Products-Release2.1-Dev-Violet\OU.Curriculum.ProductService.Installer\OU.Curriculum.ProductService.Installer.wixproj -dTargetDir=O:\TFS\Vantage\Curriculum\source\OU.Curriculum.Products-Release2.1-Dev-Violet\OU.Curriculum.ProductService.Installer\bin\Debug\ -dTargetExt=.msi -dTargetFileName=OU.Curriculum.ProductService.Installer.msi -dTargetName=OU.Curriculum.ProductService.Installer -dTargetPath=O:\TFS\Vantage\Curriculum\source\OU.Curriculum.Products-Release2.1-Dev-Violet\OU.Curriculum.ProductService.Installer\bin\Debug\OU.Curriculum.ProductService.Installer.msi -dOU.Curriculum.ProductService.Configuration=Debug -d"OU.Curriculum.ProductService.FullConfiguration=Debug|AnyCPU" -dOU.Curriculum.ProductService.Platform=AnyCPU -dOU.Curriculum.ProductService.ProjectDir=O:\TFS\Vantage\Curriculum\source\OU.Curriculum.Products-Release2.1-Dev-Violet\OU.Curriculum.ProductService\ -dOU.Curriculum.ProductService.ProjectExt=.csproj -dOU.Curriculum.ProductService.ProjectFileName=OU.Curriculum.ProductService.csproj -dOU.Curriculum.ProductService.ProjectName=OU.Curriculum.ProductService -dOU.Curriculum.ProductService.ProjectPath=O:\TFS\Vantage\Curriculum\source\OU.Curriculum.Products-Release2.1-Dev-Violet\OU.Curriculum.ProductService\OU.Curriculum.ProductService.csproj -dOU.Curriculum.ProductService.TargetDir=O:\TFS\Vantage\Curriculum\source\OU.Curriculum.Products-Release2.1-Dev-Violet\OU.Curriculum.ProductService\bin\ -dOU.Curriculum.ProductService.TargetExt=.dll -dOU.Curriculum.ProductService.TargetFileName=OU.Curriculum.ProductService.dll -dOU.Curriculum.ProductService.TargetName=OU.Curriculum.ProductService -dOU.Curriculum.ProductService.TargetPath=O:\TFS\Vantage\Curriculum\source\OU.Curriculum.Products-Release2.1-Dev-Violet\OU.Curriculum.ProductService\bin\OU.Curriculum.ProductService.dll -dVantageInstallerCustomActions.Configuration=Debug -d"VantageInstallerCustomActions.FullConfiguration=Debug|x86" -dVantageInstallerCustomActions.Platform=x86 -dVantageInstallerCustomActions.ProjectDir=O:\TFS\Vantage\Curriculum\source\OU.Curriculum.Products-Release2.1-Dev-Violet\VantageInstallerCustomActions\ -dVantageInstallerCustomActions.ProjectExt=.csproj -dVantageInstallerCustomActions.ProjectFileName=VantageInstallerCustomActions.csproj -dVantageInstallerCustomActions.ProjectName=VantageInstallerCustomActions -dVantageInstallerCustomActions.ProjectPath=O:\TFS\Vantage\Curriculum\source\OU.Curriculum.Products-Release2.1-Dev-Violet\VantageInstallerCustomActions\VantageInstallerCustomActions.csproj -dVantageInstallerCustomActions.TargetDir=O:\TFS\Vantage\Curriculum\source\OU.Curriculum.Products-Release2.1-Dev-Violet\VantageInstallerCustomActions\bin\Debug\ -dVantageInstallerCustomActions.TargetExt=.dll -dVantageInstallerCustomActions.TargetFileName=VantageInstallerCustomActions.dll -dVantageInstallerCustomActions.TargetName=VantageInstallerCustomActions -dVantageInstallerCustomActions.TargetPath=O:\TFS\Vantage\Curriculum\source\OU.Curriculum.Products-Release2.1-Dev-Violet\VantageInstallerCustomActions\bin\Debug\VantageInstallerCustomActions.dll -out obj\Debug\ -arch x86 -ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\\WixUtilExtension.dll" -ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\\WixIIsExtension.dll" obj\Debug\VantageInstallerCustomActions_Generated.wxs Product.wxs obj\Debug\Product.Generated.wxs obj\Debug\_OU.Curriculum.ProductService.wxs
2>candle.exe(0,0): error CNDL0103: The system cannot find the file 'obj\Debug\VantageInstallerCustomActions_Generated.wxs' with type 'Source'.
2>Done building project "OU.Curriculum.ProductService.Installer.wixproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 6 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Here is my solution setup:
[image: Solution Setup]

I'm struggling to understand why "VantageInstallerCustomActions_Generated.wxs" is being requested and causing the error as I have not included it. I can see it in the output but have no idea what has caused it to be added to the candle.exe cmd line. Any ideas how to remove it ?

Update: I believe it may have something to do with my OU.Wix.targets file:

```
<Project
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <MSBuild Projects="%(ProjectReference.FullPath)" 
             Targets="Package"
             Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=AnyCPU"
             Condition="'%(ProjectReference.WebProject)'=='True'" />
    <PropertyGroup>
      <DefineConstants>%(ProjectReference.Filename)_Generated.Target=%(ProjectReference.RootDir)%(ProjectReference.Directory)obj\$(Configuration)\Package\PackageTmp\;</DefineConstants>
      <CompilerAdditionalOptions>$(IntermediateOutputPath)%(ProjectReference.Filename)_Generated.wxs</CompilerAdditionalOptions>
      <LinkerAdditionalOptions>$(IntermediateOutputPath)%(ProjectReference.Filename)_Generated.wixobj</LinkerAdditionalOptions>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <HeatDirectory OutputFile="$(IntermediateOutputPath)%(ProjectReference.Filename)_Generated.wxs"
                   Directory="%(ProjectReference.RootDir)%(ProjectReference.Directory)obj\$(Configuration)\Package\PackageTmp\"
                   Transforms="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\WsxExcludeWebConfig.xslt"
                   DirectoryRefId="INSTALLFOLDER"
                   ComponentGroupName="%(ProjectReference.Filename)_Generated"
                   AutogenerateGuids="false"
                   GenerateGuidsNow="true"
                   SuppressCom="true"
                   SuppressFragments="true"
                   SuppressRegistry="true"
                   SuppressRootDirectory="true"
                   ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)"
                   Condition="'%(ProjectReference.WebProject)'=='True'"
                   PreprocessorVariable="var.%(ProjectReference.Filename)_Generated.Target"
                   />
  </Target>
</Project>
```